# difference between static T const and static const T

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios

Assuming that `T` is an arbitrary type and we're talking about Objective-C. Then what is the difference between

```
static T const x = ....
```

and

```
static const T x = ....
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the distinction is only important for pointer types; for example 'char *'.

`const char *p` means that the buffer pointed to by `p` **cannot** be updated but pointer `p` itself **can** be changed (typically incremented with p++), for example:

```
void f(const char *p)
{
    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        putc(*p);
        p++;
    }
}
```

`char * const p` means that the buffer pointed to by `p` **can** be updated but pointer `p` **cannot** be changed.

**EDIT**  Thanks for JeremyP for the following comment:

It's quite common in Apple's APIs to define string constants (instead of using #defines), especially if the string is an NSString i.e. `NSString * const kFoo = @"bar";`

Comment: If you declare a global const pointer, it catches mistaken attempts to change it.

Comment: It's quite common in Apple's APIs to define string constants (instead of using #defines), especially if the string is an NSString i.e. `NSString* kFoo const = @"bar";`

Comment: @JeremyP I think you mean `NSString * const kFoo = @"bar";`. I can't get Xcode to admit `NSString * kFoo const = @"bar";` as valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same.

---

A little background about `const`:

Objective-C, just like C, uses the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). In a case where you have only modifiers at the left side of the variable (of foo) you read stuff going from right to left:

```
int * const * var;
```

is read: *var is a pointer to a constant pointer to integer*.

However `const` has the same effect when it's before or after the first type:

```
int const var; // constant integer
const int var; // constant integer, same as above
```

---

`static`, instead, affects the whole variable: it's the variable to be static, not the element pointed by it or anything else: a pointer to integer can be used both to point to a static integer, or to an automatic integer without distinction, and C doesn't provide a syntax to declare a pointer able to point to static variables (or to automatic variables) only.

```
static int * x; // x is a static pointer to integer
int static * y; // as above y is a static pointer to integer
int * static z; // THIS SYNTAX IS NOT ALLOWED
                // but if it was, it would mean the same thing
```

For this reason I prefer to place it before any `const` modifier, but it doesn't actually matter.

```
static  const int * const * x; // this is what I do
```

Comment: That's an awesome explanation from peoro. On top of this I would like to throw in that static restricts the scope to the call (in Objective-C) to the file it is called in. I would like to know though, what's the point in combining static and constant together over just declaring something static? If you wouldn't mind going in depth in that. I do have a good reference link explaining more here: http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/12/static-constant-strings-in-objective-c/